# Why don't Stack Exchange websites show my profile picture that I have already uploaded?

Tags: bug, profile-picture, mobile-app

When setting up my profile, I uploaded my profile picture. After that, I installed the app in my tablet, but when I signed in, I didn't find my profile picture. I tried again to upload another profile picture, but I got the same result.

Comment: You uploaded it but did you actually save the changes after you uploaded? It's a two-step process. There's a save button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes I did, it even shows me the picture beside my name in the browser, but not in the app. For now, the picture is moved from the website too!